# Database not accessed

Tags: c#

The first one is funtion that i call. second one is the code to show the data that has already been stored in database. Now when i input the license number from the txtno and select the License number from combobox cbonumber and press the btnsearch, there is no record found message is shown even though the licensenumber and numbertype exists is database

function

```
 public DataTable CheckExistingLicenseNo(string LicenseNumber, string Numbertype)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security=True; Initial Catalog=tprojectDB;");
        string sql = "select *from tblDDDDDriver where LicenseNumber=@LicenseNumber and Numbertype=@Numbertype";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LicenseNumber", LicenseNumber);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Numbertype", Numbertype);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable db = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(db);
        return db; ;
    }
```

code in btnsearch

```
 private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable db = dc.CheckExistingLicenseNo(txtno.Text,cbonumbertype.Text);
        if (db.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (cbonumbertype.Text == "LicenseNumber")
            {
                txtlicenseno.Text = db.Rows[0]["LicenseNumber"].ToString();
                txtlicensecategory.Text = db.Rows[0]["LicenseCategory"].ToString();
                txtissuedate.Text = db.Rows[0]["IssueDate"].ToString();
                txtrenewdate.Text = db.Rows[0]["RenewDate"].ToString();
                txtfullname.Text = db.Rows[0]["FullName"].ToString();
                txtdob.Text = db.Rows[0]["DOB"].ToString();
                txtaddress.Text = db.Rows[0]["Address"].ToString();
                string gender = db.Rows[0]["Gender"].ToString();
                if (gender == "Male")
                {
                    txtgender.Text = " MALE";
                }
                else
                {
                    txtgender.Text = "FEMALE";
                }
                txtvehicleno.Text = db.Rows[0]["VehicleNumber"].ToString();
                txthealthstaus.Text = db.Rows[0]["HealthStatus"].ToString();
                txtdrivertype.Text = db.Rows[0]["DriverType"].ToString();

                Image img;
                byte[] bytimg = (byte[])db.Rows[0]["Image"];

                //convert byte of imagedate to Image format
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytimg, 0, bytimg.Length))
                {
                    ms.Write(bytimg, 0, bytimg.Length);

                    img = Image.FromStream(ms, true);

                    pictureBox1.Image = img;
                }

            }
            DataTable dd = dc.GetMaxDeathNo(Convert.ToDecimal(txtlicensenumber.Text));
            if (dd.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                txtdeathaccidentno.Text = dd.Rows[0]["DeathNumber"].ToString();
            }

            DataTable dM = dc.GetMaxMajorNo(Convert.ToDecimal(txtlicensenumber.Text));
            if (dM.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                txtmajoraccidentno.Text = dM.Rows[0]["MajorNumber"].ToString();
            }

            DataTable dm = dc.GetMaxMinorNo(Convert.ToDecimal(txtlicensenumber.Text));
            if (dm.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                txtminoraccidentno.Text = dm.Rows[0]["MinorNumber"].ToString();
            }

            DataTable dtrb = dc.GetTrafficRuleBroken(Convert.ToDecimal(txtlicensenumber.Text));
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dtrb;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No RECORD IS FOUND");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does it go wrong? What are the values entered? What is the contents of the database?

Comment: You should also add a try-catch statement around your SQL execution code too. This will help highlight errors within that code and would have told you that you didnt open the connection as mentioned by @MitchWheat

Comment: @MitchWheat there is no need to `Open` connection as Op is using `SqlDataAdapter`.

Comment: @Takarii there is no need to `Open` connection as Op is using `SqlDataAdapter`

Comment: Sorry, Misread the code. Add the try-catch statement and get it to throw an `SqlException`, printing that to the console to help identify

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I suspect can be causing an issue is the value of cbonumbertype.Text. Change to cbonumbertype.SelectedValue and see if that wont help.

Change

```
DataTable db = dc.CheckExistingLicenseNo(txtno.Text,cbonumbertype.Text);
```

To

```
DataTable db = dc.CheckExistingLicenseNo(txtno.Text,cbonumbertype.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that Bayeni's solution is the right one. You are possibly entering the ComboBox `SelectedItem.Text` value instead of the `SelectedItem.Value` value.

The easiest way to check this is to add a breakpoint to this line:

```
DataTable db = dc.CheckExistingLicenseNo(txtno.Text,cbonumbertype.Text);
```

In Visual Studio, select Debug > Start Debugging and check if the value in cbonumbertype.Text is the one that you expect to see.